# In-built laptop camera and mic don't work, are universal drivers available?

Tags: drivers, camera, microphone, hardware-compatibility

I am using the Eve 5 2-in-1 laptop from a small [enthusiasts manufacturer](https://euro.evedevices.com/pages/eve-v-2021-tech-specifications). The device came with windows installed and the in-built camera and microphone work with this OS. But more often I use the other partition on the device - Ubuntu 20.04.2. On it the in-built camera and mic don't work (but I can use external mics from headphones). From looking in the forums of the device I found that the device doesn't have drivers for the camera and mic for Linux. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFAkLui8WD7RtOzdtdfiHdmzEbp2U8dE/view?usp=sharing) you can see the output of my `lsusb` and `lsusb -v` commands:

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0603:00f1 Novatek Microelectronics Corp. Keyboard (Labtec Ultra Flat Keyboard)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. M-UAS144 [LS1 Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[Here](https://eve.community/t/enabling-the-vs-hardware-on-linux-wiki/12580/23) you can read a little bit more what people in the support forum have discussed. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cvS-yRCYwwdL0sGJ6Bh0XxABivRyVBzP/view?usp=sharing) is the output of `sudo lshw -class multimedi`:

```
sudo lshw -class multimedia
[sudo] password for nestor: 
  *-multimedia:0            
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Imaging Unit
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm cap_list
       configuration: driver=ipu3-imgu latency=0
       resources: irq:140 memory:dc000000-dc3fffff
  *-multimedia:1
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ipu3-cio2 latency=32
       resources: irq:142 memory:dd810000-dd81ffff
  *-multimedia:2
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:126 memory:dd838000-dd83bfff memory:dd800000-dd80ffff
```

Is there a way to make the in-built camera and mic work on Ubuntu? Are there some kind of universal drivers? Tnx

Comment: `sudo lshw -class multimedia` *might* display details of your audio. This might allow a better structured search for any necessary drivers/firmware. But it's a rather non-standard device. ;) Have you considered investigating using a mobile via USB as a camera?

Comment: @JeremyBoden Thanks, I included in my question some info. Let me know if there is something else useful I can include, I am definitely no Linux pro. Regarding your question: when I need to use the camera I switch to the Windows partition. It is easier then purchasing an external camera and carrying it around with me :)